# How much variance is explained by a given subset of variables (mixed data, both quantitative and qualitative)

Tags: variance, categorical-data, numerics

My question is very very similiar to the on asked here: [How much variance is explained by a given subset of variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279843/how-much-variance-is-explained-by-a-given-subset-of-variables)

However, I have mixed data, e.g. both categorical variables (i.e. location) and numerical variables (i.e. team size). This applies to both the complete dataset and the subset.

With qualitative data in the dataset, is multivariate regression as suggested in the previous question still applicable? I'm doubtful, but thankful for your thoughts.

If multivariate regression isn't applicable, do you know how to calculate the explained variance of the subset?

Thanks!